# Create token (password grant) for user directly without password (REST API Laravel)

Tags: laravel, rest, laravel-5, laravel-passport

everyone!
First, sorry if such issue is already was. And sorry for my English...
I am newer at laravel and I like it.
Now I learning how to create REST API app and for this I use laravel/passport.
And my target is to make social networks authorize via API. How it should work:

1. Client app, for example - mobile app, must send me (my app at laravel) request with Google token (for example).
2. From receive token I get the data about user, save it or find already existent.
3. After that I must send a token (from my app, not Google one), refresh token and expires_at.

Of course in normal api auth I use password_grant where you must do request with login and password, and it generate token, refresh token,expires_at. But how to do it if you have not password? How to create token, refresh token and expires_at for special user?
I know about personal tokens, but it only 'longlive' token? It make no sense! Why is not exist personal token that go with refresh token and expires_at or password token where you can create it directly?
Is there are some right solution? Will be solution in a future version of laravel/passport?

I will be very thankful if you can advise some really good solution.

Comment: Aren't you looking for something like this https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/socialite ?

Comment: No, I already use it. I need to do my own token from  google token. For example, user login via Google in mobile app, he got token that goes to me (my site at laraevel), I registrate him with data from token and generate my token (not google) and send him back. Then mobile app will use this token to autorize user.